# Laravel: How to display OneToMany in a View

Tags: laravel, relationship

Help Please.

Newbie here. I need to display the name of Patron and Item instead of displaying their id. I have 3 tables:

Patrons (id, name), Items (id, name), Transactions (patron_id, item_id, loaned, due, returned)

Patron model

```php
    public function transaction ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }
```

Item model

```php
    public function transaction ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }
```

Transactions model

```php
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
    }

    public function patrons()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Patron::class);
    }
```

This is the part where I'm really confused. I don't know how to code the TransactionController and the View.

Transaction Controller: (Is this even right?)

```php
        $transactions = Transaction::paginate(10);
        return view('transactions.index')->with(compact('transactions'))->with('patrons', Patron::all())->with('items', Item::all());
```

index.blade.php (I don't know how to code this)

```php
@foreach($transactions as $transaction)
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">{{ $transaction->patron_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $transaction->item_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $transaction->Loaned }}</td>
    <td>{{ $transaction->Due }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

The View displays like this:

```
1     1     2020-09-21
2     5     2020-09-21
```

But I need it to display like this:

```
John Doe      Harry Potter        2020-09-21
Mary Jane     Game of Thrones     2020-09-21
```

Comment: in your blade file `<td>{{ $transaction->patron->name }}</td><td>{{ $transaction->item->name }}</td>` and you can just return `return view('transactions.index')->with(compact('transactions'));`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried it but I get this error: "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Comment: sry in your relationship its partons not patron `{{ $transaction->patrons->name }}`

Comment: I changed it but I get the same "non object" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is coming from how you are pulling data from the database and how you are pushing it to the view.

For retrieving data, you can eager load your `transactions` model with all of its relationships in one go and [paginate](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results) at the same time:

```
$transactions = Transaction::with('patron', 'item')->paginate(15);
```

Take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views) on views, there are a number of ways of transferring data.  Compact works pretty well and is easy to understand with multiple returns, so I'll give an example of that here:

```
return view('transactions.index', compact('transactions'));
```

And that's it - just remember to type the variable `transactions` within quotes and not put the actual variable inside the compact method.

Then, because you have eager loaded the relationship, in your view you can now call upon the relationship **name** instead of just the id number.  For example:

```
<td>{{ $transaction->item->name }}</td>
```

Suggest you rename the relationship from patrons to patron as it is a belongsTo.

Comment: Wow! It's working and I learned so many things today. Thank you very much Watercayman. I really appreciate it. I've been at this for a very long time.